# Vue - unable to pass values from method property to a data object

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2, payment-gateway

I want to be able to pass values into my data object (payment: {}) from my method property when executing a function. I'm using a payment gateway system called PayHere for testing purpose. I'm finding it hard to pass my values into its given function (payhere.startPayment(this.payment);).

You may find PayHere's javascript sdk using this link: https://support.payhere.lk/api-&-mobile-sdk/payhere-javascript

When I ran it I got the following error:

```
payhere.js:1 POST https://sandbox.payhere.lk/pay/checkout 500

startPayment @ payhere.js:1
addOnlineCheckoutItem @ CustomerViewCart.vue?4f1c:206
click @ CustomerViewCart.vue?1a55:156
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1863
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2188
original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6961
VM715:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest._0x5c7b34.<computed> (payhere.js:1)
    at Object.startPayment (payhere.js:1)
    at VueComponent.addOnlineCheckoutItem (CustomerViewCart.vue?4f1c:206)
    at click (CustomerViewCart.vue?1a55:156)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1863)
    at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2188)
    at HTMLButtonElement.original._wrapper (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6961)
```

This is my checkout page

```
<template>
  <div class="customer-view-cart">
    <div>
      <form style="margin-left:3%; width: 460px ">              
      <p class="check-info">
          <b>Billing Info</b>
        </p>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: left">Sub Total</td>
              <td style="text-align: right">Rs. {{ subTotal }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: left">Shipping Fee</td>
              <td style="text-align: right">Rs. 150</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- <tr>
              <td style="text-align: left">Price Total</td>
              <td align="right">$84.82</td>
            </tr> -->
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: left">Total</td>
              <td style="text-align: right">Rs. {{ total }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
        <br />
        <div class="line"></div>

        <p class="check-info"><b>Payment Method</b></p>
     

        <button           
          @click.prevent="addOnlineCheckoutItem()"
          id="payhere-payment"
        >
          <i
            style="margin-right: 0.5rem; color: var(--secondary)"
            class="far fa-credit-card"
          ></i
          >Online Payment
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <empty-cart></empty-cart>
    </div>
    <mini-cart></mini-cart>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { dbItemAdd, dbOrders } from "../../main";
import firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/firestore";  

export default {
  name: "CustomerCheckout",
  components: { MiniCart, EmptyCart },
  data() {
    return {
      cartDump: [],
      // cartItems: [],
      profiles: [],
      profile: "",
      orders: [],
      order: {},
      cartItems: [],
      payment: {},

      picked: "",
    };
  },
  created() {},
  beforeCreate() {
    this.$store.dispatch("setItems");
  },
  firestore() {
    return {
      items: firebase.firestore().collection("products"),
      reviews: firebase.firestore().collection("reviews"),
      profiles: firebase.firestore().collection("profiles"),
      orders: firebase.firestore().collection("orders"),
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addOnlineCheckoutItem() {
      payhere.onCompleted = function onCompleted(orderId) {
        console.log("Payment completed. OrderID:" + orderId);
        //Note: validate the payment and show success or failure page to the customer
      };

      // Called when user closes the payment without completing
      payhere.onDismissed = function onDismissed() {
        //Note: Prompt user to pay again or show an error page
        console.log("Payment dismissed");
      };

      // Called when error happens when initializing payment such as invalid parameters
      payhere.onError = function onError(error) {
        // Note: show an error page
        console.log("Error:" + error);
      };

      this.payment = {
        sandbox: true,
        merchant_id: "1218995", // Replace your Merchant ID
        return_url: undefined, // Important
        cancel_url: undefined, // Important
        notify_url: "http://sample.com/notify",
        items: "bell",
        order_id: "order123",
        items: "Door bell wireles",
        amount: "cart.price",
        currency: "LKR",
        first_name: "Cahill",
        last_name: "Sam",
        email: "sam@mail.com",
        phone: "012345xxxxx",
        address: "address,123",
        city: "Colombo",
        country: "Sri Lanka",
      };   
      payhere.startPayment(this.payment);
    },      
 },    
};
```

The payment values aren't being passed into "this.payment" object on the data property.

Comment: where is import statement for payer?

Comment: im sorry? do you mean the script link for payhere payment gateway? the script has been added on my index.html page

Comment: From the error message, it seems like your request causes a server error and sandbox server returns  an error response in html instead of json. Check your network tab in browser dev tools and read the error response body there.

Comment: thank you. that was helpful.